# How to implement post api calls using thunk middleware in react-redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I was working with redux-thunk and superagent npm for jwt authentication  and i would want to know how to implement post calls using thunk-middleware in the actions.js file and not in the main reducer.js file

Comment: Is this use case not the one described in the redux-thunk documentation in combination with the fetch api or axios?

Comment: the redux-thunk documentation have described only about fetch api calls and not post call.. i need to hit a post api call here :)

Comment: The Fetch API covers post requests, too. The intention of my comment was to show you that async requests (async actions, you looked for that) are documented and it requires minimal effort to apply the samples to your situation. Because you didn't provide any source or any kind of specific problem (other than "i need todo this"), and the answer is pretty basic, the only answer u get are people implementing it for you in little lines of code, not the kind of question for SO in my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of different ways to go about it, but I personally like to use the axios library. Axios essentially just assists with making an API request and parsing the data back from the API into json.

In your actions.js file.

```
export const authenticateUser = () => {
 return (dispatch, getState) => {
    //get the token from the reducer 
    const jwtToken = getState().jwtTokenReducer.tokenKey
    axios.post("/api/authenticate-user", jwtToken) //jwtToken passed into request
       .then((res) =>){
           dispatch({
              type: "AUTHENTICATE_USER",
              payload: res.data
           })
       }
       .catch((errors) => {
            dispatch({
               type: "ERRORS",
               payload: errors.response.data
            })
        })
 }
}
```

So take a look at the above syntax. Typically when you define an action-creator, you setup a function that returns an action (object). But thanks to redux-thunk, you can now setup your action-creators to return functions with dispatch as an argument.

So in your returned function you can define certain logic, like making a request to an API like we did up there. Then we can take that data by using the `.then` promise handler and use it as a payload for an action that we would explicitly dispatch to our reducers.

Comment: ..And i need to send my jwt token in the header along with the axios post call !

Comment: That would be correct, assuming you need the jwt token in order to authenticate through the back-end :)

Comment: is there any way i could send the token in the above mentioned post call?

Comment: Sure there is, but it would depend where the jwt-token is coming from. Are you getting the jwt-token from the API itself, or are you handling that logic on the front-end?

Comment: handling it on the front-end bro..Like i have described, i have used superagent npm library for recieving and sending jwt from localstorage(if there is any) . This superagent request is coded in reducer file and i need to do that in actions.js

Comment: Ah for sure dude, that makes our action creators even more interesting. I can update my answer for you, but essentially we'll be using something called getState() which is also available thanks to redux-thunk. You get the data from the reducer and pass it into your request.

Comment: Great! Let me know if that works for you. I'm happy to help you with any questions.

Comment: @SuryaPranesh. Were you able to find an answer to your question :)?

Comment: i just used headers in my post call including jwt token in it and it works fine ! Thank you broo

Comment: @SuryaPranesh. You're welcome bro! If that's all you need, could you please mark this as the answer. That will mark this question as resolved. Also, let me know if you have any other questions about react/redux :)